# Repetiton of using Ctrl+S in Word 2010 causes word to crash

Tags: microsoft-word

When working with Word 2010 documents, I am finding that repetitive use of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> causes word to crash and a temporary folder is created. I am using Windows 10. Any suggestions on how to resolve this will be very much appreciated!

Comment: You may have some funky settings.  Look carefully at File -> Options -> Save.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I checked those settings against another computer and they are set up identically so those settings look to be ok.  If you have any other thoughts, that would be great!